# Is there a maximum value for upstart's kill timeout setting?

Tags: upstart, timeout

Upstart's [`kill timeout`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#kill-timeout) will let a service take some amount of time to shut down gracefully before being `SIGKILL`ed.  I have a service that could take minutes or hours to exit gracefully (and I'd like it to take that long), will `kill timeout` work for multi-hour timeouts?  Or is there some maximum timeout Upstart will allow?

I notice that [`launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) specifies if `ExitTimeOut` is `0` the timeout will be infinite.  Is an infinite timeout possible in Upstart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't specify any. See [`init/parse_job.c`, function `parse_kill`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/upstart/wily/view/head:/init/parse_job.c#L2004):

```c
if (! strcmp (arg, "timeout")) {
    nih_local char *timearg = NULL;

    /* Update error position to the timeout value */
    *pos = a_pos;
    if (lineno)
        *lineno = a_lineno;

    timearg = nih_config_next_arg (NULL, file, len,
                       &a_pos, &a_lineno);
    if (! timearg)
        goto finish;

    errno = 0;
    class->kill_timeout = strtol (timearg, &endptr, 10);
    if (errno || *endptr || (class->kill_timeout < 0))
        nih_return_error (-1, PARSE_ILLEGAL_INTERVAL,
                  _(PARSE_ILLEGAL_INTERVAL_STR));
}
```

Aside from the obvious limit of the max value of `long`, it seems you can use anything.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted!  So it seems there's [still](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-dfsg-5.1/+bug/620441) no way to specify an infinite timeout, right?

Comment: Since a `long` is usually 64-bits on an 64-bit system, and [since MySQL uses 32 bits for timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#cite_note-10), meaning in effect you can have a timeout that's longer than anything meaningful for MySQL, yes, you can.

Comment: Sorry, my use-case isn't related to MySQL, it's just an old related issue I stumbled upon.  Tools like [`launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) provide a mechanism for "never timeout" (the `ExitTimeOut` property can be set to `0`), but it seems you must always specify a non-zero value for Upstart.  Certainly I can just specify a very large value and call it good, but I was curious if there was a way to be explicit about it.